# Python psd_tools : 'module' object has no attribute 'profile_frombytes'

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library

running the following code:

```
from PIL import *
from psd_tools import *
psd = PSDImage.load('test.psd')
```

I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    psd = PSDImage.load('test.psd')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psd_tools/user_api/psd_image.py", line 192, in load
    return cls.from_stream(fp, encoding)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psd_tools/user_api/psd_image.py", line 200, in from_stream
    psd_tools.reader.parse(fp, encoding)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psd_tools/decoder/decoder.py", line 30, in parse
    image_resource_blocks = image_resources.decode(reader_parse_result.image_resource_blocks),
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psd_tools/decoder/image_resources.py", line 58, in decode
    return [parse_image_resource(res) for res in image_resource_blocks]
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psd_tools/decoder/image_resources.py", line 68, in parse_image_resource
    return resource._replace(data = decoder(resource.data))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psd_tools/decoder/image_resources.py", line 141, in _decode_icc
    return ImageCms.ImageCmsProfile(io.BytesIO(data))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageCms.py", line 158, in __init__
    self._set(core.profile_frombytes(profile.read()))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'profile_frombytes'
```

I have taken steps to reinstall PIL, Pillow, psd-tools, and dependencies.

I am at a loss to get to the bottom of this.

Running Python 2.7 on Mac OSX 10.7.5

edit:
here is the output requested--

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imagingcms.so:
    /usr/local/lib/liblcms.1.0.19.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 2.19.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
```

Pillow version :
2.5.0

Comment: What version of `lcms` is your `PIL` linked against? Could you include the output of `otool -L /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imagingcms.so` in your question please?

Comment: Also, what version of `Pillow` are you using? (`import PIL; print PIL.PILLOW_VERSION`)

Comment: Ok, that Pillow version *should* have the `profile_frombytes` method defined on `_imagingcms` (which is aliased to `core`). That method seems to have been introduced in [this commit](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/commit/9631d42b60ec3f62c571bff6094424e1c98ba51c), which is definitely in the 2.5.0 branch. So I assume your rather old version of `lcms` is the problem.

Comment: `from PIL import ImageCms; ImageCms.core.profile_frombytes` works for me with `lcms-2.2`, `PIL-2.5.0`, Python 2.7.1 on OS X 10.7.5. So I would suggest you try upgrading to `lcms2` (you need to rebuild `Pillow` after that). So `brew install lcms2` if you're using [homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

Comment: brew install little-cms2

Comment: pip uninstall pillow
pip install pillow

Comment: Great, glad it worked! If you want to post the exact steps that worked for you as an answer to your own question, I'd be happy to upvote :)

Comment: Will do.  I have to wait eight hours though  :(

Answer (score 1):

Answer found from Lukas Graf.  See comments above.

Little CMS needed updating to latest version.

```
$ brew install little-cms2
$ pip uninstall pillow
$ pip install pillow
```